# Weird output "<Buffer" in child_process.spawn

Tags: javascript, mongodb, child-process, spawn

Trying to write a script to dump my MongoDB to afterwards restore it in a Test database again.

```
const {spawn} = require('child_process');

const backupDB = spawn('C:\\_Apps\\mongo\\bin\\mongodump.exe', [
    '--host', 'localhost',
    '--port', '27019',
    '--collection', 'ops',
    '--db', 'prod',
    '--out', "C:\\_Apps"],
    {shell: true}
);

backupDB.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());
});

backupDB.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('Error: ', data);
});

backupDB.stderr.on('close', (code) => {
    console.log('Exit Code: ', code);
```

Weirdly the script does what it is supposed to (I can find the output BSON under the specified location), but the output is cryptic:

```
    Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 30 38 2e 37 33 32 2b 30 32 30 30 09 77 72 69 74 69 6e 67 20 73 6d 61 72 74 4f 52 2e 6f 70 73 20 74 ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 31 31 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 31 34 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 31 37 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 32 30 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 32 33 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 32 36 2e 32 36 34 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 32 39 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 33 32 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 33 35 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 33 38 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 34 31 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 34 34 2e 32 36 36 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 34 37 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 35 30 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 35 33 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 35 36 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 36 3a 35 39 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 30 32 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 30 35 2e 32 36 36 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 30 38 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 31 31 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 31 34 2e 32 36 36 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 31 37 2e 32 36 36 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 32 30 2e 32 36 36 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 32 33 2e 32 36 36 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 32 36 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 32 39 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 33 32 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 33 35 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 2e 2e 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 33 38 2e 32 36 35 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 2e ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 34 31 2e 32 36 36 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 34 33 2e 33 34 32 2b 30 32 30 30 09 5b 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 23 ... >
Error:  <Buffer 32 30 31 39 2d 30 36 2d 32 37 54 31 34 3a 32 37 3a 34 33 2e 33 34 32 2b 30 32 30 30 09 64 6f 6e 65 20 64 75 6d 70 69 6e 67 20 73 6d 61 72 74 4f 52 2e ... >
Exit Code:  false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That output is just encoded text.

Try this to see the real output:

```
backupDB.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
    console.log('Error: ', data.toString('ascii'));
});
```

Note that this output is coming from **stderr**, not **stdout**

The stuff that you posted translates as:

```
2019-06-27T14:26:08.732+0200    writing smartOR.ops t
2019-06-27T14:26:11.265+0200    [....................
2019-06-27T14:26:14.265+0200    [....................
2019-06-27T14:26:17.265+0200    [....................
2019-06-27T14:26:20.265+0200    [....................
2019-06-27T14:26:23.265+0200    [....................
2019-06-27T14:26:26.264+0200    [....................
2019-06-27T14:26:29.265+0200    [....................
2019-06-27T14:26:32.265+0200    [....................
2019-06-27T14:26:35.265+0200    [....................
2019-06-27T14:26:38.265+0200    [....................
2019-06-27T14:26:41.265+0200    [###.................
2019-06-27T14:26:44.266+0200    [###.................
2019-06-27T14:26:47.265+0200    [###.................
2019-06-27T14:26:50.265+0200    [###.................
2019-06-27T14:26:53.265+0200    [###.................
2019-06-27T14:26:56.265+0200    [###.................
2019-06-27T14:26:59.265+0200    [###.................
2019-06-27T14:27:02.265+0200    [###.................
2019-06-27T14:27:05.266+0200    [###.................
2019-06-27T14:27:08.265+0200    [###.................
2019-06-27T14:27:11.265+0200    [###.................
2019-06-27T14:27:14.266+0200    [#####...............
2019-06-27T14:27:17.266+0200    [#####...............
2019-06-27T14:27:20.266+0200    [#######.............
2019-06-27T14:27:23.266+0200    [########............
2019-06-27T14:27:26.265+0200    [##########..........
2019-06-27T14:27:29.265+0200    [############........
2019-06-27T14:27:32.265+0200    [##############......
2019-06-27T14:27:35.265+0200    [#################...
2019-06-27T14:27:38.265+0200    [###################.
2019-06-27T14:27:41.266+0200    [####################
2019-06-27T14:27:43.342+0200    [####################
2019-06-27T14:27:43.342+0200    done dumping smartOR.
```

Comment: Thanks. Why would this data come from stderr?

Comment: This is quite normal, stdout is often used for outputting the actual "result" of the operation (for example, mongodump can write to stdout rather than to a file), so stderr is used for things like progress and information.

Comment: I am starting two mongorestore instances from child_process, sometimes one is stuck at 100% and doesn't return a close event. Any idea?

Progress:  2019-06-27T21:19:46.962+0200 [########################]  test_dev.collection 1.39MB/1.39MB  (100.0%)
Progress:  2019-06-27T21:19:49.962+0200 [########################]  test_dev.collection 1.39MB/1.39MB  (100.0%)

Answer (score 1):

You can decode it like this:

```
backupDB.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
 console.log(Buffer.from(data).toString());
});
```

Inside `toString()` you can provide any [encoding](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) you want